# issue with withRouter high order function in "react-router": "^4.0.0-beta.5"

Tags: react-router

I have the component declared in the following syntax:

```
const HomePage = observer(withRouter(React.createClass({
...})
```

the observer is the mobx function which is used to react to the state change, but it doesn't detect the change after I upgrade to the latest react-router v4. I really need somebody look into the issue and help me out.

Comment: Oh I found the solution is change the wrap order!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the wrapping order of the functions and it works!